# What data is shared between browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, privacy, metadata

I will set the stage -  I use Google Chrome and Firefox. On my chrome I am signed in with all my accounts and have multiple adblockers, tracker blocker, HTTPS only plugins etc. I usually use Firefox for content I do not want to be tagged to my accounts, profile etc.

Because I use ad blockers I didn't realize this but there is some data being shared between browsers. Specifically, I binged watched series of YouTube videos on Firefox and somehow those videos were being recommended to me on my signed in YouTube account on Chrome. How is this possible? What other data is being shared? How do I avoid this leak/ cross over of data I want to keep anonymous.

Comment: Google owns youtube. This is why it happens

Comment: [Content blocking | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/content-blocking)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your browser being readily [identified by fingerprinting](https://restoreprivacy.com/browser-fingerprinting/), use a browser designed for increased anonymity, such as Firefox-based [TOR browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) or [an alternative](https://techviral.net/best-anonymous-browsers/).

However, you can still be identified by other information "leaked" from your web connection. For example, even if you have geolocation turned off in the browser and in the operating system, your ISP provides the location of your connection. View the information visible to any web site and test your browser's anonymity and security at one of the following:

- [Anonymity Check](https://proxy6.net/en/privacy)
- [Cyber Lab](https://www.elfqrin.com/binfo_check_anonymity.php)
- [Panoptclick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
- [Qualys BrowserCheck](https://browsercheck.qualys.com/)
- [BrowserAudit](https://browseraudit.com/)

You can use a VPN to hide your ISP and IP address, with the *caveat* that some sites, particularly those that have distribution controlled by region or nationality, may reject your connection through VPN. After all, if they cannot monetize the connection, why let you browse? Also, some material may be protected by copyright in one location and not another. Remember that [Amazon removed *1984* from Kindle readers](https://www.cnet.com/news/amazon-recalls-and-embodies-orwells-1984/) because of a regional copyright issue?